# React Higher Order Components: Proper way to add instance methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I am trying to add instance methods to a wrapped component. I am doing this by extending the wrapped component's prototype:

```
const useAppContext = () => WrappedComponent => {
    WrappedComponent.prototype.$context = { abc: 'abc' };
    return class extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
    };
};

@useAppContext()
class NavigationLinkList extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log('this.$context', this.$context);
    };
};
```

While this *works* I am not sure if there is a cleaner way to do this, one that is the "regular" way with react. I could not find anything in the docs and this ways seems a bit like a hack. Are there other (cleaner?) ways to do it?

Answer (score 2):

A more cautious way is to not modify class prototype but extend it:

```
const useAppContext = () => WrappedComponent => {
    return class extends WrappedComponent {
        $context = { abc: 'abc' };
    };
};
```

At this point this is just a decorator and isn't valid higher-order component because it can't work with functional components.

A way that is idiomatic to React is to use composition rather than inheritance. A common way to extend the functionality of existing component in higher-order component is to provide necessary functionality through props, since props are the primary way to communicate between components in React:

It can be:

```
const useAppContext = () => WrappedComponent => props => {
    return <WrappedComponent $context={{ abc: 'abc' }} {...props} />;
};
```

and

```
@useAppContext()
class NavigationLinkList extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.$context);
        ...
    };
};
```

Comment: React will warn about `$context` not being a valid attribute name though :)

Comment: @antoinechalifour Will it? $context isn't valid HTML attribute but it's valid *prop* name.

Answer (score 0):

A higher order component usually add functions to the wrapped component props, not to its prototype.

Adding methods to the prototype makes the wrapped component coupled to the decorator (meaning it wont work when it is not decorated) and will make it harder to test.

Plus, a estus mentioned, it will not work with function components.

You could always rewrite your decorator to inject the context in the wrapped component props as such :

```
const useAppContext = () => WrappedComponent => {
    WrappedComponent.prototype.$context = { abc: 'abc' };
    return class extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} context={{ adb: 'abc')} />;
        }
    };
};
```